# Appcode folder cs class which can set the controls on an aspx page

Tags: c#, class, controls, app-code

I am new to c# and I have created several classes as methods in my appcode folder. These are called from the main class, which is the code behind for an aspx page with lots of HTML controls.  The methods being called will want to make visible/invisible some of these asp HTML controls, like Gridview1 or Label1. However, these appcode classes do not see the main class's controls.  I have tried to inherit the main class but that doesn't seem to allow me to do that.  Am I missing a concept here? Do I need to use namespaces? Do I need a Using directive? Do I need to prefix my main class in some way to inherit it.  I would have thought that any method could see the main aspx controls so I am missing something.  Would you have an example of a simple code-behind cs (A), and a simple appcode folder cs (B) which makes (A's) controls Invisible?

Answer (score 1):

if you are using ASP.NET:

You then have a `.aspx` file, which contains your controls (such as labels, textboxes, etc..). You will also have a `.cs` file, that "works together" with your `.aspx` file.

lets say you have the following code:

```
     <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm7.aspx.cs" Inherits="Test.WebForm7" %>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org /TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <asp:Label id="ThisIsYourLabel" runat="server" text="Make me invisible"/>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

in your `.cs` file, which is specified in the page directive (`CodeBehind="WebForm7.aspx.cs"`) , you can access your controls.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace Test
{
    public partial class WebForm7 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ThisIsYourLabel.Visible = Tools.ChangeVisibility();
        }
    }
}
```

in your case, you have a set of methods in your app_code folder.

i made a small method in app_code:

```
public class Tools
{
    public static boolean ChangeVisibility()
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

in other words: you can acces the controls you have on an `.aspx` page in the `.cs` file. You can't directly access the controls from 1 certain `.aspx` page in your app_code folder. You could change the access level from protected to public in the `designer.cs` file of your page, **but i would certainly not advise you to do so**.

if you run this code, you won't see anything in your browser because the label will be set to `Visible = false;`, but if you debug it you will see how it works :)

hope it helps!

Comment: Jane, thank you.  In the example, what I would like to do is in the Tools class, instead of return false, actually set ThisIsYourLabel = false.  I guess the answer is as you noted, I cannot access the control this way.  Also, I think your example gives me a framework in which I might be able to work with.  Again, Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

i think this might helps you..,you can try something like this...in your class file under appcode folder..

```
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
public class Tools()
{

public static void set_label_properties(Label lb)
{

lb.Visible=false;
lb.Text="Your status msg..";


}

}
```

and in your aspx.cs file , you need to call this method..wherever you need..and pass the appropriate Web Control(Label) as your method parameter..

```
Tools.set_label_properties(Label1);
```